# Is a map grid considered tabular data in semantic HTML?

Tags: html, css, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I'm working on a browser based game, and want to keep the HTML as semantically correct as possible.

The base of the game is a "board" made up of a grid of tiles. The coordinates of each tile are used as a way to refer to each tile - much like in Battleships.

Would it be correct semantic markup to use a table to represent this kind of "map" grid, or as it's not a table of figures, would it be more correct to use block level elements such as divs to build up the grid? [image: Example coordinate grid]

[edit] In response to some comments, if I should/shouldn't use `<table>` - why not?

Comment: I'm afraid this is asking for opinions, but my opinion is that grids this are one case where simulating a table with `<div>` and `display:table` is a good solution. (This in contrast to many situations where people just simulate tables to layout their page; which I think is abusing tables just as badly as using `<table>`  elements.)

Comment: "Semantic markup" is about subjective interpretations of vague parts of specifications. The question is really "Would you call this tabular data?"

Comment: The irony is that for the actual game like this, you shouldn't use `<table>`, while if you were to show example setups (of possible game situations), those would really be considered data, and a `<table>` would be OK. Even if the grid is the same.

Comment: @MrLister - I guess that's the crux of the question, and what I should've asked - if I shouldn't use `<table>` for the game - why not?

Comment: Because the game layout is not a representation of a set of data. Even though it has, as @Alohci says, "the hallmarks of a table", the contents are not tabular data. However, again, this is subjective. Everyone has an opinion about this, it is the subject of much heated debate, you won't get any consensus.

Comment: @MrLister - thanks for expanding. Having looked at this again, I think I''m gonna close this question, as it does seem to be a case of opinion rather than there being a "correct" way. Thanks for the input all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen reader or text browser users would have a hard time to play this game if you’d *not* use a `table`.

If you use `div` elements to build that grid, you would have to be very verbose about which cell has which coordinates (each cell would need to be labeled explicitly), and the players would need to concentrate to "rebuild" this grid in their mind. Like playing chess via phone. Possible, yes, but harder than having the board in front of you.

So yes, I think you should use a `table`. The order of grid cells *is* important and meaningful, and each cell is labeled by two headings (x/y axis).

Using a `table`, your grid would be perfectly usable by screen reader users (most screen readers can announce the headings/coordinates of the cells) and in a text browser, too (w3m in this case):

[image]

Try that without a `table`. `div` elements have no concept of top/right/bottom/left neighbours.

Comment: Good point that I hadn't thought of. Considering most folks think it's subjective to ask which is correct - perhaps the question should be "which is the easiest for everyone to use?" Thanks Unor

Answer (score 1):

It has the hallmarks of a table. 2D, header cells for both axes, and the meaning of the content would change if the tiles were laid out differently.

Comment: Thanks for the input - as others have pointed out, this is probably too subjective to have a correct answer though, so I'm gonna just close the question.